# Saving string when field is nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Item Schema:

```
new Schema({
    name: {
        ka: String,
        en: String
    }
});
```

When doing like this:

```
Item.findOne({}, function(err, item){
    item.name = 'wrongtype';
    item.save();
});
```

item's name property is saved to database, despite of fact that name is described as object in schema. Validation is not working. Can you suggest solution? Or explain if it's correct behaviour

Comment: Sorry @JohnnyHK I had bad example. Updated quesiton. Can you please retry to reproduce this issue? Thanks

Comment: OK, now I can reproduce it. Weird, that sure looks like a bug.